# mysql_real_escape_string() causing segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, c, api, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a *C* program that uses the `mysql.h` library. This is the code:

```
  int newproduct(){
    char *name;//nombre del prducto
    char *desc;//descripcion del producto
    double price;//precio del producto
    cprint("Agregar nuevo producto\n\n");
    printf("Nombre del producto: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Descripcion: ");
    scanf("%s", &desc);
    printf("Precio: ");
    scanf("%e", &price);

    MYSQL *conn;
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
    user, password, database, port, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    char *rname = NULL;//string donde guardar el nombre con caracteres de escape
    char *rdesc = NULL;
    mysql_real_escape_string(conn,rname,name,strlen(name));//se realiza el real escape
    mysql_real_escape_string(conn,rdesc,desc,strlen(desc));
    /*
    char *query;//donde guardar el query

    snprintf(query,1000,"INSERT INTO productos (nombre,descripcion,stock,precio) VALUES( %s,%s, 0, %e)",rname,rdesc,price);//query a enviar

    if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {//enviar el query
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }*/

    mysql_close(conn);

return 0;
}
```

And this is the console execution

```
Agregar nuevo producto

Nombre del producto: a
Descripcion: a
Precio: 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


------------------
(program exited with code: 139)
Press return to continue
```

I'm sure that the `mysql_real_escape_string` is causing the segmentation fault because when I comment it the code works fine but it's my first time working with MySQL and I have no clue why this is failing. Besides that i was able to retrieve some info from the database so its not a connection error.
PD: cprint is a declared function that adds a header to the printf function containing mysql row data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rname` and `rdesc` are supposed to be buffers, not pointers to `NULL`. You must alloc the memory space first.

For instance:

```
char rname[1024];
char rdesc[1024];
mysql_real_escape_string(conn, rname, name, 1024);
mysql_real_escape_string(conn, rdesc, desc, 1024);
```

Also, the size of `rname` cannot be `strlen(name)`, because the escape characters will require extra space. The required buffer may have to be up to four times bigger than the original string.

Comment: the buffer, according to the docs has to be 2 times the length of the original string plus one (for the null terminator). This is the worst case scenario (aka, buffer is nothing but single quotes for example).

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//mysql-real-escape-string.html) the `to` argument:

```
unsigned long mysql_real_escape_string(MYSQL *mysql, char *to, const char *from, unsigned long length)
                                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

which in your case is `rname` and `rdesc` need to have space allocated to them. The documents specifically say:

```
You must allocate the to buffer to be at least length*2+1 bytes long.
```

You are also not using [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) correctly with `name` and `desc` since neither has space allocated to them. Something like the following would work:

```
char name[80];
scanf("%s", name);
```

If we go with the a size of `80` for `name` then following the document, the following would work for `rname`:

```
char rname[161] ;
```